# How do I restrict the day and month of a DATE to be one of two different dates?

Tags: oracle, date, constraints, ddl

How to check if inputted date is one of two options.

I'm trying to create a table with a enrollment date ('DD.MM.YYYY') and that enrollment should be only possible on April first or on October first. 
I've been trying different ways but can't make it work.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  student_id CHAR(10),
  enrollment_date DATE CHECK (enrollment_date = TO_DATE('01.04','DD.MM') OR enrollment_date = TO_DATE('01.10','DD.MM'))
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  student_id CHAR(10),
  enrollment_date DATE CHECK (enrollment_date = TO_DATE('01.04','DD.MM') OR enrollment_date = TO_DATE('01.10','DD.MM'))
);
```

In both cases I got:

> ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK
>   constraint 02436. 00000 - "date or system variable wrongly specified
>   in CHECK constraint" *Cause: An attempt was made to use a date
>   constant or system variable, such as USER, in a check constraint that
>   was not completely specified in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE
>   statement. For example, a date was specified without the century.
>   *Action: Completely specify the date constant or system variable. Setting the event 10149 allows constraints like "a1 > '10-MAY-96'",
>   which a bug permitted to be created before version 8.

Comment: Try `EXTRACT(DAY FROM enrollment_date) = 1 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enrollment_date) IN (4,10)`

Comment: Or you can also try `to_char(enrollment_date, 'dd.mm') in ('01.04', '01.10')`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it worked both ways, and also thanks for the edition, it was my first question and wasn't sure how to write everything, actually I just realized I wrote the same code twice.